# How to integrate firebase with laravel socialite

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Good day!

I am looking for a good resource on how to integrate firebase with laravel socialite. I am currently working on a PHP laravel project. I have integrated laravel socialite but my user model is just local (stored in database). Now, I want to integrate firebase into the project but I cannot seem to figure out how to authenticate users.

This is the code I use to sign in users:

```
    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $githubUser = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        $user = User::where('provider_id', $githubUser->getId())->first();

        if (!$user) {
            // add user to database
            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $githubUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $githubUser->getName(),
                'provider_id' => $githubUser->getId(),
            ]);
        }

        // login the user
        Auth::login($user, true);

        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }
```

For local models, this works fine but I am confused if this will work if I use firebase models.

```
 * The user model will be stored in firebase firestore database
```

Is this something possible with socialite and firebase? If you need more information please let me know. Thank you for your answer and have a good day!

Comment: I may be wrong but Socialite is designed for building social login, and Firebase is also designed for something similar. You would probably be better off just choosing one of them and using that.

Comment: I am using firebase just for database (not authentication) and socialite as authentication. Isn't that possible?

Comment: It just seems like a long way around. What does firebase offer that a standard DB cannot?